# Java Instantiating the implementation of Queueadt

Tags: java, arrays, queue

This is a general question about the syntax of instantiating an ADT implementation.

So I created a class call Airline that implements the Queue interface and I needed an instantiation of an arrival queue, for example, based off of the Airline type

What is the difference between

```
private Queue<Airline> queue = new Queue<>();
```

and

```
private Queue<Airline> queue = new Queue<Airline>();
```

Comment: No difference, the former is syntactic sugar

Comment: The only difference is that first code sample would only compile with java 7 and higher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private Queue<Airline> queue = new Queue<Airline>();
```

The above is how generic types have had to be specified since they were released in Java 5. You have a `Queue` of generic type `Airline`, so you *instantiate* it as such (on the right hand side) and *declare* it as such (on the left hand side.)

Java 7 however introduced the [diamond operator](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2074080/core-java/jdk-7--the-diamond-operator.html), which allows the generic type that's being *instantiated* to be infered from the generic type that's *declared*:

```
private Queue<Airline> queue = new Queue<>();
```

So in this example, the compiler infers that the instantiated type should be `Queue<Airline>` from the declaration, and treats it as such.

As said in the comments above, the difference is purely syntactic sugar, so purely with compilation. The compiled bytecode and thus runtime behaviour will be identical for both cases.